# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'ModularWebApp.Models.LutUsers[]'

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net, json, api

i have this code , and i'm trying to retrive json data from a c# web api, when ever i try to deserialize the json i'm getting : **Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'ModularWebApp.Models.LutUsers[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'content', line 1, position 11.'**

i tried a lot of other ways to do and it still not working , any help?

here is my model

```
    [JsonProperty("matricule_agent")]
    public string  matricule_agent {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("grade_agent")]
    public string grade_agent { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("nom_utils")]
    public string nom_utils { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("prenom_utils")]
    public string prenom_utils { get; set; }
```

and Here is my controller

```
  public ActionResult LutUser()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your LookUp Table Page.";
            List<LutUsers> lutUsers = new List<LutUsers>();
            LutUsers[] Users = new LutUsers[0];
            
       
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress + 
           "/user/findusers").Result;
            //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Connection Made successfully!');</script>");
                         JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                       // Person[] persons = js.Deserialize<Person[]>(json);
                        string data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    lutUsers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LutUsers>>(data);

                // lutUsers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LutUsers>>(data);
                      Response.Write(Users);


            } else
                {             

                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Connection not made!');</script>");
                }
                //returning the employee list to view  
                return View(lutUsers);

        }
```

Comment: Like the bold text says, if you want to deserialize into an array, JSON expects the text to also contain an array like `[ {"name":"value"} ]`. Note that `[]` in JSON notates an array of whatever.

Comment: i did it that way, and it did not work also

Comment: So what does your json `data` look like?

Comment: {"content":

[{"id_utilisateurs":1,
"matricule_agent":"BE4",
"nom_utils":"laguerre",
"prenom_utils":"Vellie","sexe_utils":"F",
"dat2naiss_utils":"15-12-2020",
"grade_agent":"Agent 4",
"email_utils":"Laguerre.vellie@gmail.com",
"mot2pass_utils":null,
"typ_compte":"agent",
"is_active_utils":1,
"date_enreg_utils":"05-05-2021 15:55:00",
"affectation":"villate","is_first_login":1,
"mot2pass_utils_defaut":null
}],

"status":"success"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is what your data looks like,

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "id_utilisateurs": 1,
      "matricule_agent": "BE4",
      "nom_utils": "laguerre",
      "prenom_utils": "Vellie",
      "sexe_utils": "F",
      "dat2naiss_utils": "15-12-2020",
      "grade_agent": "Agent 4",
      "email_utils": "Laguerre.vellie@gmail.com",
      "mot2pass_utils": null,
      "typ_compte": "agent",
      "is_active_utils": 1,
      "date_enreg_utils": "05-05-2021 15:55:00",
      "affectation": "villate",
      "is_first_login": 1,
      "mot2pass_utils_defaut": null
    }
  ],
  "status": "success"
}
```

then you need to have the rootObject that has content as a list/array of objects (`Content`).

```
public class Rootobject
{
    [JsonObject("content")]
    public List<Content> Content { get; set; }
    [JsonObject("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class Content
{
    public int id_utilisateurs { get; set; }
    public string matricule_agent { get; set; }
    public string nom_utils { get; set; }
    public string prenom_utils { get; set; }
    public string sexe_utils { get; set; }
    public string dat2naiss_utils { get; set; }
    public string grade_agent { get; set; }
    public string email_utils { get; set; }
    public object mot2pass_utils { get; set; }
    public string typ_compte { get; set; }
    public int is_active_utils { get; set; }
    public string date_enreg_utils { get; set; }
    public string affectation { get; set; }
    public int is_first_login { get; set; }
    public object mot2pass_utils_defaut { get; set; }
}
```

Remember, your data is an object that contains content and status as the keys. content's value is an array.. so, deserialize it like this,

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(data)
List<Content> lutUsers = rootObject.Content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create class

```
public class ResultData
{
    public int id_utilisateurs { get; set; }
    public string matricule_agent { get; set; }
    public string nom_utils { get; set; }
    public string prenom_utils { get; set; }
    public string sexe_utils { get; set; }
    public DateTime dat2naiss_utils { get; set; }
    public string grade_agent { get; set; }
    public string email_utils { get; set; }
    public string mot2pass_utils { get; set; }
    public string typ_compte { get; set; }
    public int is_active_utils { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_enreg_utils { get; set; }
    public string affectation { get; set; }
    public int is_first_login { get; set; }
    public string mot2pass_utils_defaut { get; set; }
}
```

and replace

```
    lutUsers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LutUsers>>(data);
```

with

```
var resultData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResultData>>(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data you care about is buried in the `content` array.

Wrap your `LutUsers` class in a container class with the following properties:

```
public List<LutUsers> content {get; set;}
public string status {get;set;}
```

Comment: Yes , that is what was missing , thank you.